# Should we localize scope variables at cost of multiple declarations

Tags: java, software-design

Effective java greatly stresses on localizing scope of variable. But in case we have an if else it may cause multiple declations eg:

```
   public List<E> midPoint() {

        if (first == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("Linked list is empty");
        }
    if (first.next == null) {
        ArrayList<E> arr = new ArrayList<E>();
        arr.add(first.element);
        return arr;
    }

    Node<E> fast = first.next;
    Node<E> slow = first;

    while (fast != null && fast.next != null) {
        slow = slow.next;
        fast = fast.next.next;
    }

    // even count for number of nodes in linkedlist.
    if (fast != null) {
        ArrayList<E> arr = new ArrayList<E>();
        arr.add(slow.element);
        arr.add(slow.next.element);
        return arr;
    } else {
        ArrayList<E> arr = new ArrayList<E>();
        arr.add(slow.element);
        return arr;
    }
}
```

In the above code Arraylist defination / declaration occurs multiple times, but the variable is localized.. Is it good the way it is OR should arrayList be declared at the top and returned where its matches condition : eg:

```
public List<E> midPoint() {

    if (first == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("Linked list is empty");
    }

    ArrayList<E> arr = new ArrayList<E>(); // NOTE - JUST A SINGLE DECLARATION.
    if (first.next == null) {
        arr.add(first.element);
        return arr;
    }

    Node<E> fast = first.next;
    Node<E> slow = first;

    while (fast != null && fast.next != null) {
        slow = slow.next;
        fast = fast.next.next;
    }

    // even count for number of nodes in linkedlist.
    if (fast != null) {
        arr.add(slow.element);
        arr.add(slow.next.element);
        return arr;
    } else {
        arr.add(slow.element);
        return arr;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: While I generally agree with IHawk answer, I would not consider any option "better" than the other. The first is more formal and safe, I would use the latter mainly for "end of method" code where it is easy to check that you will not be reusing it in a wrong way. It is true that tomorrow another programmer can change that, but if the method is kept simple enough (as it should) then it is less of an issue. The renaming is good advice, I almost always use `returnValue` for such constructs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with declaring it multiple times, but you have a lot of repeated code: you can significantly improve your code by refactoring.

In your case, the JDK provides a convenience utility method to create ArrayLists in-line:

Instead of:

```
ArrayList<E> arr = new ArrayList<E>();
arr.add(slow.element);
arr.add(slow.next.element);
return arr;
```

Code this:

```
return Arrays.asList(slow.element, slow.next.element);
```

And so forth.

---

Note that the list returned from `asList()` is not modifiable. If you need a modifiable list, pass it to [`ArrayList`'s copy constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28java.util.Collection%29):

```
return new ArrayList(Arrays.<E>asList(slow.element, slow.next.element));
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case, it is advised that you declare it in only one place.  It will be more readable and spare some lines of code.

Renaming would also be good, maybe something that suggests that is the final result of your method (like `returnArray`, `resultArray`).

In other circumstances, when that list would mean several different things, it would be really better to declare it, in that case, you would have different names too.

Answer (score 1):

> Should we localize scope variables at cost of multiple declarations

Different people (including well respected authors of well-known text books) will have different opinions on what makes code readable.  The problem, is that readability is a subjective measure: it depends on the reader.

So I think it is up to you to decide.  The chances are that you are going to be the primary reader of your code, at least to start with.  So ...

- Use the version that *you* think makes the code more readable.
- If you want a second opinion, ask your co-workers.
- If you have chosen to use a style guide ... be guided by what it says.

---

FWIW, my personal opinion is that it really depends on the context.  Sometimes it is better to localize, sometimes not.  A lot depends on how "far away" the declaration is from the usage, and how intuitive the meaning of the variable is.  (For example, if `arr` was named `res` or `result`, you would not need to look at the variable declaration ... assuming you knew the signature of the current method.)